# R dplyr subset alternative

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I want to break a dataframe ("inputfile") into 2 parts (A and B, where B is (not A) ). Right now that seems to involve distinct `subset()` calls and two `dplyr` sentences.

Here is what I have now, which is fine, but requires two passes:

```
library(stringr)

data(mtcars)
mtcars$makemodel <-rownames(mtcars)

mtcars%>%subset( str_detect(makemodel, "Mazda")) -> A
mtcars%>%subset(!str_detect(makemodel, "Mazda")) -> B

dim(A)
dim(B)
```

Is there a way to do this:

```
inputfile%>% split_data(condition, A, B)
```

so that if condition was true the record would flow to data frame A, and if the condition was false it would flow to B?

Comment: You're looking for `group_by`, which makes splitting unnecessary. In this case, something like `mtcars %>% add_rownames('car') %>% group_by(group = grepl('Mazda', car))`

Answer (score 0):

`split` is one way to go, which divides your data frame into a list of two sub data frames based on your condition:

```
library(stringr)
split(mtcars, str_detect(mtcars$makemodel, "Mazda"))
```

Without the `stringr` package, `grepl` should be enough for your case here:

```
split(mtcars, grepl("Mazda", mtcars$makemodel))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a grouping variable with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
d1 <- copy(mtcars)
setDT(d1, keep.rownames=TRUE)[, grp := str_detect(rn , "Mazda")][]
```